# How can i modify a remote file over ssh with sed?

Tags: linux, bash, unix, sed

i am trying to add a line to the top of a JS file on a remote server
the command i want to run is:

```
sed -i "1i\const test = require(\'../../../test/test.json\');" /opt/test.js
```

so i have tried the following:

```
ssh user@host "sed -i "1i\const test = require(\'../../../test/test.json\');" /opt/test.js"
```

this gives me an error due to the "(" and ")" so i added a "\" before them:

```
ssh user@host "sed -i "1i\const test = require\(\'../../../test/test.json\'\);" /opt/test.js"
```

however i still get the error:

```
bash: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

how can i fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than use `sed -i` (which just manages a temp file behind the scenes), use `ed` and provide the script (via `ssh`) to `ed`'s standard input.

```
ssh user@host 'ed /opt/test.js' <<'EOF'
1i
const test = require('../../../test/test.json');
.
wq
EOF
```

Comment: thanks, this works well, but it wont allow me to add a variable inside the string. if you change test to $test and test=123 , do you know how i can make it write the variable to the file?

Comment: I quoted the `EOF` delimiter under the assumption you didn't want to make any substitutions like this. Just use `EOF` instead of `'EOF'`.